# Complex query (django ORM or SQL)

Tags: sql, django, orm

I'm getting stuck on a complex query, trying to use Django's ORM.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    deprecated = models.ForeignKey(SpecialVersion, null=True)

class Version(models.Model):
    compatible_from = models.ForeignKey(SpecialVersion)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class SpecialVersion(models.Model):
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

The gist of this is, Products have multiple Versions. Some of these Versions are 'special' - we keep track of this by making a SpecialVersion object pointing to the 'special' Version object. When we create a non-special version, it must indicate a compatibility with a SpecialVersion. That is, starting at the SpecialVersion indicated by compatible_from. A Product can become deprecated at a certain special version.

Now, I want to be able to find appropriate Products given a certain SpecialVersion. In other words, I want to get all Product objects where there is a Version available that has a SpecialVersion below my given SpecialVersion. Furthermore, the Product's deprecated SpecialVersion must be either null, or below the given SpecialVersion if not null.

TL;DR:
Select all Products where the given SpecialVersion is in the range between the lowest compatible_from SpecialVersion in the product, and the deprecated SpecialVersion (if this exists).

EDIT: Example.

Products
id | deprecated
0  | None
1  | 2

Versions
id | prd | compat
0  | 0   | 1
1  | 0   | 2
2  | 1   | 2

SpecialVersions
id | ver | ord
0  | Null | 1
1  | Null | 2
2  | Null | 3
3  | Null | 4

A query for compatibility w/ SpecialVersion would return no products, because none of the products have versions that specify a compatibility as low as that. A query for compat w/ SpecialVersion would return all of the Products because they both have compatibility starting at SpecialVersion id=1 and id=2, respectively. Finally, a query for compat w/ SpecialVersion would return ONLY the product id=0 because though both products have a SpecialVersion compat low enough, the second product has been deprecated for SpecialVersions and upwards.

Comment: Could you provide some faux data and show which rows you would want selected based on an example request?

Comment: I made the SpecialVersions have a null version field, because that bit doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
products = Product.objects.annotate(min_version=Min(version_set__compatible_from__order)).filter(min_version__lte = given_special_version).filter(Q(deprecated__isnull = True) | Q(deprecated__order__gt = given_special_version))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is the [Django Q Object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). This allows you to use complex lookups such as "OR" statements in your query. If I understand your question correctly, something along the lines of this should work just fine:

```
from django.db.models import Q
models.Product.objects.filter(Q(deprecated__isnull=True) | Q(version__compatible_from__order__lte=GIVENSPECIALVERSION)).all()
```

Where *GIVENSPECIALVERSION* is the version order that you received from somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Close, but not quite - I need to check for deprecation (ie - if NOT null, then make sure I am below the deprecated version). Furthermore, there is no version field - it's a foreignkey, so you only get version set which requires annotation. See my answer below.

Comment: @guywhoneedsahand Ah, gotcha. Tried to wrap my head around your setup. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit convoluted. Thanks.